# How to apply a for loop to a string in Python

Tags: python

How do I apply a for loop to a string in Python which allows me to count each letter in a word? The ultimate goal is to discover the most common letter.

This is the code so far:

```
 print "Type 'exit' at any time to exit the program."

 continue_running = True
 while continue_running:


word = raw_input("Please enter a word: ")
if word == "exit":
    continue_running = False

else:
    while not word.isalpha():
        word = raw_input("ERROR: Please type a single word containing alphabetic characters only:")
    print word

    if len(word) == 1:
        print word + " has " + str(len(word)) + " letter."
    else:
        print word + " has " + str(len(word)) + " letters."

    if sum(1 for v in word.upper() if v in ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]) == 1:
        print "It also has ", sum(1 for v in word.upper() if v in ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]), " vowel."
    else:
        print "It also has ", sum(1 for v in word.upper() if v in ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]), " vowels."

    if sum(1 for c in word if c.isupper()) == 1:
        print "It has ", sum(1 for c in word if c.isupper()), " capital letter."
    else:
        print "It has ", sum(1 for c in word if c.isupper()), " capital letters."

    for loop in word:
```

I know I can use the:

```
(collections.Counter(word.upper()).most_common(1)[0])
```

format, but this isn't the way I want to do it.

Comment: Example added, last line of code is the only problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply loop directly over strings; they are sequences just like lists and tuples; each character in the string is a separate element:

```
for character in word.upper():
    # count the character.
```

Counts can then be collected in a dictionary:

```
counts = {}
for character in word.upper():
    # count the character.
    counts[character] = counts.get(character, 0) + 1
```

after which you'd pick the most common one; you can use the `max()` function for that:

```
most_common = max(counts, key=counts.__getitem__)  # maximum by value
```

Demo:

```
>>> word = 'fooBARbazaar'
>>> counts = {}
>>> for character in word.upper():
...     # count the character.
...     counts[character] = counts.get(character, 0) + 1
... 
>>> counts
{'A': 4, 'B': 2, 'F': 1, 'O': 2, 'R': 2, 'Z': 1}
>>> max(counts, key=counts.__getitem__)
'A'
```

Comment: How could I use this to help me count characters from word?

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly new to this. I have written the first two pieces of code you wrote and ran the module, and nothing has happened.

Comment: @poddpython: did you try to print anything? Something probably happened, but if you don't produce output to show anything you won't notice.

Comment: word.upper() is the correct thing, I'm just struggling to get this to work. Sorry

Comment: I just got something, I'll edit the question for you to see. :)

Comment: @poddpython: I added a demo of what my answer produces; using the interactive interpreter can make it easier for you to see what goes on as you experiment with code.

Comment: Thanks, my latest code is very similar, I'm just stuck on printing a formal version of the most popular character.

Comment: @poddpython: I reverted your question edit, as it wasn't actually showing your problem. Note that your questions should remain useful to future visitors too; others with similar problems should be able to read your question and understand if it applies to their situation, and how the answers then might help them.

Comment: @poddpython: read through my answer carefully; you appear to be counting characters correctly, but missed the `max()` function call after the loop to get the most common character.

Comment: Ok sorry, I just done it again because I thought it was a glitch :S

Comment: Not a problem, I rolled back again and added back in the requirement not to use Counter, since another poster now gave you that solution.

Comment: Thanks, I hope you saw where I got to. I now need to understand how to print the character with the most common value. Are the underscores "__getitem__" an example of something else I should be using? Thanks @MartijnPieters

Comment: @poddpython: I used a shortcut to get the values out of a dictionary for a given key. You can also use `max(counts, key=lambda key: counts[key])` if that makes it easier for you to see what it does.

Comment: What do I print for the final character with the most occurences? Thanks

Comment: @poddpython: my answer assigned it to `most_common`.

Comment: I can't see most_common in your latest answer.

Comment: I have just seen it and my latest code is not working.

Comment: I will answer my own question with my latest code, so please point any errors I have made. thanks

Comment: @poddpython: look closely at the demo session. The `max()` call takes place *after the loop has completed*. You put it *inside* the loop, so you keep calculating the `most_common` value after each individual character has been counted.

Comment: I have got it to work... sort of, it prints the correct letter, just not how many times it has appeared.

Comment: @poddpython: then also print `counts[most_common]`. The dictionary holds the counts still, that information hasn't gone anywhere, so just *access it*.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to re-invent the wheel try using `Counter`

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x = Counter("stackoverflow")
>>> x
Counter({'o': 2, 'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'e': 1, 'f': 1, 'k': 1, 'l': 1, 's': 1, 'r': 1, 't': 1, 'w': 1, 'v': 1})
>>> print max(x, key=x.__getitem__)
o
>>>
```

Comment: The OP managed to remove that again from their question, but they explicitly stated they did **not** want to use a `Counter()`. Also, why are you ignoring the `Counter.most_common()` method to get the most common character?